# Centering circle with flexbox column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have code below for a layout I am trying to create using flexbox. Instead of having the circle centered above the second column, is it possible to get it centered with the first column and staying centered when the screen gets resized? What steps would I have to take to achieve something like this? Anything helps, thanks. Here's the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/ColeGwoz/pen/ZxagqG?editors=1100)

```css
.profile-picture {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 55px;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.image {
  background-image: url('');
}

.profile-bio {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 550px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}

.profile-bio:before {
  content: '';
  float: left;
  padding-top: 100%;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-post {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 275px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}

.flex-post:before {
  content: '';
  float: left;
  padding-top: 100%;
}

.flex-post:hover {
  background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="profile-picture image">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-post"></div>
  <div class="flex-post"></div>
  <div class="flex-post"></div>
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-post"></div>
  <div class="flex-post"></div>
  <div class="flex-post"></div>
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-post"></div>
  <div class="flex-post"></div>
  <div class="flex-post"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/Holunderbaum/live/qopNOg)

With the percentage values which are used here, you get a size relative to the width of the [containing block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block).

You could nest all `flex-post` in one `flex-container` with this css:

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.flex-post { 
  width: 30%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.flex-post:nth-child(3n+3) {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.flex-post:nth-last-child(1),
.flex-post:nth-last-child(2),
.flex-post:nth-last-child(3) {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: I changed the Pen. I used min-width and the circle's proportions don't change anymore but it does eventually get bigger than flex-post. When I use max-width it kind of disappears, for whatever reason. Maybe you can do it with max-width and a pseudo-element similar to flex-post

Comment: I dont want the circle to change size when the screen size changes though

Comment: It's 150px now but flex-post changes as it's size is relative. And eventually becomes smaller than the circle

Comment: I found out why with max-width it broke: you need a width for it to work properly e.g. width: 100%

Comment: Couldnt get the max width to work still, could you try updating your codepen with the max width?

Comment: now, the circle tries to be as wide as its containing box and can be up to 150px wide. If the parents' width falls below 150px, the circle shrinks.

Comment: Ahh you're awesome!